# Need help regarding use of URA2415YMD-15WR3 DC to DC converter

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, flow-sensor

I have a MFC from Horiba which uses +15 V, -15 V, and 0 V for its supply. I have not found any ready-made power supply for that, so I have bought a 24 VDC to 15 VDC converter (model: [URA2415YMD-15WR3](https://www.mornsun-power.com/html/pdf/URA2415YMD-15WR3.html)) which gives me the voltages mentioned above.

I have bought the DIP package. Do I need other components in order to use this converter, or I can just mount it on any PCB and solder it to my connectors and it's ready to use?

This is the MFC I'm using:

[image: This is the MFC I'm using]
[image: This is the pin configuration for MFC]

Comment: What current does the MFC need? This will determine if your chosen DC/DC converter will do the job. Apart from that: the datasheet recommends adding input and output capacitors, and also gives their values, but doesn't say they are absolutely necessary (as far as I saw quickly scanning the datasheet). I would add them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added the current requirements in this post. I had a confusion between EMC compliance circuit and typical usage circuit as per the datasheet. I'll have to try typical usage circuit I guess.